# recommendation for neo4j in polyglot environments

Tags: rest, transactions, neo4j

What would be the recommended approach to go with Neo4j in a polyglot database environment? I guess the RESTFUL server helps you to scale your database tier well. But one of the good reasons to go with Neo4j would also be because its a transactional property graph db. But with RESTful access for neo4j when you are employing multiple databases (like mysql and neo4j for instance) , how do you manage transactions (when neo4j is exposed over REST)

Comment: I am wondering if Spring-Data provides declarative transaction support over two data-sources. My hunch is that it does, but would have to read up on it.

Comment: the chainedTransaction manager should work on an embedded Neo4j, but when it is a RESTful exposition you would typically have problems. More due to nature of REST than Neo4j. But then the RESTful exposition is the recommended one for scale.